# Changing body css from within an Angular component

Tags: css, angular

Angular4

Hi All.  I'm have a single page within a large Angular4 app that needs to have body css that's different to the rest of the app.

I don't want to set ViewEncapsulation.None because it's just the one component that needs to be affected.

Can I use :host(), :host-context() or ::ng-deep in some way to select the body and apply the css rules?  If so then how please?  If not, is there another way to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: ng-deep will be getting deprecated (if it's not already, if I remember right) but I think for your instance you could like `:host ::ng-deep body {}`

Answer (score 3):

Thank you both very much.  @Palpatine1991, you asked why I would want to access the `<body>` DOM element.  This is because I have one page in the app which is a full screen game that is played on mobile devices and has drag and drop functionality within it.  On iOS the "bounce" effect present in Safari makes drag and drop a very poor experience.  So I wanted to add the following css to the body and html DOM elements of that single page, which suppresses that bounce effect.:

```html
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

I had a look into the solutions you gave (thank you!) and went with the following solution:

```html
  ngOnInit() {
    this.renderer2.addClass(document.body.parentElement, 'wholeClassGameBody_student');
    this.renderer2.addClass(document.body, 'wholeClassGameBody_student');
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.renderer2.removeClass(document.body.parentElement, 'wholeClassGameBody_student');
    this.renderer2.removeClass(document.body, 'wholeClassGameBody_student');
  }
```

This seems to work.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to add your CSS to `<body>` if it affects only one component?

- Using `:host()` it will apply the styles to the element which is selected by component's selector.
- Using `::ng-deep` you can select only elements which are somewhere under the host element (but `<body>` is not under your host!)

The only way how to change the styles of the body from the component which has `ViewEncapsulation.Emulated` is using the `Renderer2` API but it seems to me like a very bad practice

If you need to override some global `<body>` styling of your component, you can do it using `:host-context`. Example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-issue-oodjmm